# Multi MySQL 'Servers' or 'Instances' to the same datadir

Tags: mysql

I have a project where I will need to use MySQL server. I have a shared drive and I do not have permission to make the MySQL server public by domain, meaning that only localhost works.

I can place the datadir on the shared drive and I can connect the first MySQL client/server/instance to the datadir with my portable MySQL.

The problem comes when I run another portable MySQL client/server/instance on another PC to the same datadir that was on the shared drive. It gives an error saying that the datadir is already in use.

Can anyone tell me how can I make more than one MySQL connect to that datadir at the same time?

This is to make an app with Visual Basic to manage the database so I need to have the server connection and only works with localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I may not exactly understand what you want, but :

- If you only need a local DB, like a flat-file storage, use [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/)
- If you need to run more than one MySQL server on the same pc, you'll have to custom the port they're bound to (default `3306`)

## See also :

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/multiple-servers.html
- [mysql multiple instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200785/mysql-multiple-instances)
- [MySQL local multiple instances not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557452/mysql-local-multiple-instances-not-working)

Comment: Ok what i want is the link number 2 and 3 BUT with the same datadir in the 2 instances.

Comment: @AntonioJorge and if you make two sub-folder `/datadir/sub1/` and `/datadir/sub2/` ? because mysql will probably put lock on file in the folder to avoid concurrent change by two different instance

Comment: but that way i wont be able to change the data from like the same tables with the 2 diferente instances :/

Comment: @AntonioJorge That's exactly what I was thinking : **YOU SHOULD NOT CHANGE THE DATA WITH TWO INSTANCE** ; MySQL is a DB software, that mean is like a space ship : you don't change a wing for a pink one because it's pretty. Only one MySql can change the content of the Table. If you need concurrent access, you'll have to set a main server somewhere on the network. if you can't, then, go for a SQLite file on the shared part. Be careful, even if SQLite allow concurrent read query of the same DB by multiple instance, the write will lock it for some ms, so it's not a good choice for many write.